# what is the cause for my console app exiting with code 0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line

I'm trying to call a site via its url to build a webscraper, but when i try to grab the items from the awaited url my application stops and brings up this message:

```
blablah.exe (process 1512) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stop
```

I dont think this is a code issue, perhaps something with my visual studio debugger? for the life of me can't see what it is.

This is a .net core command line app

Some code just in-case

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetHtmlAsync();

    }

    private static async void GetHtmlAsync()
    {
        var url = "https://blahblah.com";

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);


        var newsList = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class","")
            .Equals("itemList")).ToList();


        Console.WriteLine(newsList);


        Console.Read();


    }
}
```

when debugging it never even reaches:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
```

any ideas?

Comment: The most likely cause is an unhandled exception. Add debugging code like a try/catch with error logging. You can also check the system event log, often times exceptions are also logged there but it depends on the system and configured settings.

Comment: You started an asynchronous function in Main, then exited your program.  It's like putting a cake in the oven, then immediately selling the oven before the cake is done.

Comment: `0` is a normal exit. You don't await `GetHtmlAsync` so the application exits normally before that method had a chance to finish.

Comment: @Wyck There goes my Friday night laughs, great analogy.

Comment: "I dont think this is a code issue" -- of course it is. "perhaps something with my visual studio debugger?" -- blaming the tools is a common beginner error. Try it in release mode--you'll get the same result (but without the popup box).

Comment: @Igor -- no, that's not likely at all. An unhandled exception would be reported and would not result in a 0 exit code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple problems here

1) When you call `GetHtmlAsync()` you are not awaiting it, meaning your application continues to run the code after it (of which there is none), leading to the app exiting

2) You should [avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) `async void` except for event handlers, instead return `async Task`

Modified code might look like this

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await GetHtmlAsync();
}

private static async Task GetHtmlAsync()
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

Note that in order to use `async Task Main` you need to be using at least C# 7.1

Comment: oh yeah i should defo not code with the flu, so embarrassing to let this slip by!

Comment: Happens to the best of us

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's returning 0 (zero), success, is because it exited without error.

Change the method to:

`private static async Task GetHtmlAsync()`

And call it like this:

`GetHtmlAsync().Wait();`

The method will run synchronously, but the app does anyway, as written.

Comment: C# allows `async Task Main`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That depends on the version.

Comment: C# 7.1 to be exact, `async Task Main` is also just syntactic sugar which compiles to `GetHtmlAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, if I'm reading the [Async main method docs correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main). Not really worth the effort in my opinion if you work in a regulated/controlled environment where build servers often run out of date software because ops teams don't/won't actively pass the responsibility to developers and instead you have to jump through hoops for a simple C# or .NET upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Faced a similar issue like this, and there were arguments required in the code which I was not providing. Worked after provided correct arguments.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. "This happened to me too" is not an appropriate answer, but could be added as a comment to the question. (You can do so once you have sufficient reputation.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).